# Music play when cursor on button

Tags: javascript, html, css

This a code when we click on the button then music will play.
But I want when cursor move over the button then music should play.
What changes will be do in the code given below?

//CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
nav#nav1{
 margin-top: 24px; 
}

nav#nav1 > a{
 background:#B9E1FF; color:#000; padding:10px; text-decoration:none;
  border-radius:5px;
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif; 
}
nav#nav1 > a:hover{ 
  background: #BBEA00; 
}
nav#nav1 > a:active{ background: #EEFFA8; }
</style>
<script>

var bleep = new Audio();
bleep.src = 'myMusic.mp3';
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav id="nav1">
    <a href="#" onmousedown ="bleep.play()">Home</a>
    <a href="#" onmousedown="bleep.play()">About Us</a>
    <a href="#" onmousedown="bleep.play()">Services</a>
    <a href="#" onmousedown="bleep.play()">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code has a spurious space after one of the onmousedown which means that one will not work.

Comment: I edited my answer and included a comment about that redundant space after the first onmousedown.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `onemousedown` with `onmouseover`, and it will work like you describe.

You could also use `onmouseenter` to start the music and stop it with the `onmouseleave` event.

You have a redundant space before the Home onmousedown, by the way.

If the sound doesn't work, your beep.play() function isn't working. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_audio_play) is a code example of how you can do it.

You could add the url of the mp3 inside the audio function, like `new Audio(url)` and this will preload the sound file. Check that the path to your mp3 file is correct, this might be the only problem with your code (except for that extra space you have to remove).

Comment: Just for the record: I commented above on the original question, but I updated this answer after @NaeemAmin said it didn't work. It seems like the updated solution has helped.